# Error connecting to MongoDB: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'db')

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express

```
const mongoDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
        console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
        const fetched_data = await mongoose.collection.db.collection("guideInfo");
        fetched_data.find({}).toArray(function (err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            else console.log(data);
        })
        // Your code here
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', error);
    }
};

module.exports = mongoDB;
```

This was the code I was expecting to see the data from my mongoDB, but it showed an error instead, i don't know what could be the reason

```
 at mongoDB (C:\Users\acer\Desktop\disha\guide\backend\db.js:19:52)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Comment: Your database connection was not sucessful. Check if your mongod service is runing/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```js
await mongoose.collection.db.collection("guideInfo");
```

try this:

```js
await mongoose.connection.db.collection("guideInfo");
```

Comment: oh thank you it worked, but the terminal doesn't show the info that I have in that particular collection, why could that be?